# Is there a way to replace "Corr" values with actual graphs in R?

Tags: r

Here's the dataset I'm using: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3nv38jjo5dxcl6/nba_2013.csv?dl=0`, it contains statistics for NBA players.

And I want to see how different columns correlate with each other, thus I want to draw pairwise scatterplots.

Here's my code:

```
library(GGally)
nba %>%
    select(ast, fg, trb) %>%
    ggpairs()
```

nba variable contains the whole dataset

And when I want to draw the pairwise scatterplot, I get something like this:

Generated Output

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0pLn.png]

However, some of the graphs are replaced by "Corr" values, is there a way to replace these "Corr" values with actual graphs so that the output looks as follows:

Desired Output

[image]

Comment: You do realise that the "missing" scatterplots are the same as the shown scatterplots, except that they are reflected across the diagonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an approach:

```
nba %>%
  select(ast, fg, trb) %>%
  ggpairs(upper = list(continuous = "points", 
          combo ="facethist", discrete = "facetbar", na = "na"))
```

[image]